# python list/dict property best practice

Tags: python

I have a class object that stores some properties that are lists of other objects. Each of the items in the list has an identifier that can be accessed with the `id` property. I'd like to be able to read and write from these lists but also be able to access a dictionary keyed by their identifier. Let me illustrate with an example:

```
class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class Teacher(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class Classroom(object):
    def __init__(self, children, teachers):
        self.children = children
        self.teachers = teachers

classroom = Classroom([Child('389','pete')],
                      [Teacher('829','bob')])
```

This is a silly example, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do. I'd like to be able to interact with the classroom object like this:

```
#access like a list
print classroom.children[0]
#append like it's a list
classroom.children.append(Child('2344','joe'))
#delete from like it's a list
classroom.children.pop(0)
```

But I'd also like to be able to access it like it's a dictionary, and the dictionary should be automatically updated when I modify the list:

```
#access like a dict
print classroom.childrenById['389']
```

I realize I could just make it a dict, but I want to avoid code like this:

```
classroom.childrendict[child.id] = child
```

I also might have several of these properties, so I don't want to add functions like `addChild`, which feels very un-pythonic anyway. Is there a way to somehow subclass dict and/or list and provide all of these functions easily with my class's properties? I'd also like to avoid as much code as possible.

Comment: How about `classroom.childrenBy('Id')['389']` or something like that?

Comment: That could work, but I'd still have to define a childrenBy method for every property, and then I'd have to do a linear search through the children list to find the id that matches. I'd like to update the dictionary when the list changes.

Comment: When you said "I also might have several of these properties", I thought you meant several properties like `id`. Did you mean several properties like `children`? If so, could you have `classroom.ById('Child')['389']`?

Comment: @Gabe yes, I meant several like ``children``. I tried to illustrate this by adding ``teachers`` in there too. That method could work, but it doesn't solve the problem of having to do a linear search through the children property when ``ById`` is called. I want to somehow keep an up-to-date dictionary as ``children`` is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An indexed list class:

```
class IndexedList(list):
    def __init__(self, items, attrs):
        super(IndexedList,self).__init__(items)
        # do indexing
        self._attrs = tuple(attrs)
        self._index = {}
        _add = self._addindex
        for obj in self:
            _add(obj)

    def _addindex(self, obj):
        _idx = self._index
        for attr in self._attrs:
            _idx[getattr(obj, attr)] = obj

    def _delindex(self, obj):
        _idx = self._index
        for attr in self._attrs:
            try:
                del _idx[getattr(obj,attr)]
            except KeyError:
                pass

    def __delitem__(self, ind):
        try:
            obj = list.__getitem__(self, ind)
        except (IndexError, TypeError):
            obj = self._index[ind]
            ind = list.index(self, obj)
        self._delindex(obj)
        return list.__delitem__(self, ind)

    def __delslice__(self, i, j):
        for ind in xrange(i,j):
            self.__delitem__(ind)

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        try:
            return self._index[ind]
        except KeyError:
            return list.__getitem__(self, ind)

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):            
        return IndexedList(list.__getslice__(self, i, j))

    def __setitem__(self, ind, new_obj):
        try:
            obj = list.__getitem__(self, ind)
        except (IndexError, TypeError):
            obj = self._index[ind]
            ind = list.index(self, obj)
        self._delindex(obj)
        self._addindex(new_obj)
        return list.__setitem__(ind, new_obj)

    def __setslice__(self, i, j, newItems):
        _get = self.__getitem__
        _add = self._addindex
        _del = self._delindex
        newItems = list(newItems)
        # remove indexing of items to remove
        for ind in xrange(i,j):
            _del(_get(ind))
        # add new indexing
        if isinstance(newList, IndexedList):
            self._index.update(newList._index)
        else:
            for obj in newList:
                _add(obj)
        # replace items
        return list.__setslice__(self, i, j, newList)

    def append(self, obj):
        self._addindex(obj)
        return list.append(self, obj)

    def extend(self, newList):
        newList = list(newList)
        if isinstance(newList, IndexedList):
            self._index.update(newList._index)
        else:
            _add = self._addindex
            for obj in newList:
                _add(obj)
        return list.extend(self, newList)

    def insert(self, ind, new_obj):
        # ensure that ind is a numeric index
        try:
            obj = list.__getitem__(self, ind)
        except (IndexError, TypeError):
            obj = self._index[ind]
            ind = list.index(self, obj)
        self._addindex(new_obj)
        return list.insert(self, ind, new_obj)

    def pop(self, ind=-1):
        # ensure that ind is a numeric index
        try:
            obj = list.__getitem__(self, ind)
        except (IndexError, TypeError):
            obj = self._index[ind]
            ind = list.index(self, obj)
        self._delindex(obj)
        return list.pop(self, ind)

    def remove(self, ind_or_obj):
        try:
            obj = self._index[ind_or_obj]
            ind = list.index(self, obj)
        except KeyError:
            ind = list.index(self, ind_or_obj)
            obj = list.__getitem__(self, ind)
        self._delindex(obj)
        return list.remove(self, ind)
```

which can be used as:

```
class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class Teacher(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class Classroom(object):
    def __init__(self, children, teachers):
        self.children = IndexedList(children, ('id','name'))
        self.teachers = IndexedList(teachers, ('id','name'))

classroom = Classroom([Child('389','pete')], [Teacher('829','bob')])

print classroom.children[0].name               # -> pete

classroom.children.append(Child('2344','joe'))
print len(classroom.children)                  # -> 2
print classroom.children[1].name               # -> joe
print classroom.children['joe'].id             # -> 2344
print classroom.children['2344'].name          # -> joe

p = classroom.children.pop('pete')
print p.name                                   # -> pete
print len(classroom.children)                  # -> 1
```

**Edit:** I had made a mistake in some of the exception-handling (catching KeyError instead of IndexError); it is fixed. I will add some unit-testing code. If you run into any further errors, please let me know!

Comment: This is great. Did you just whip this up?

Comment: Yes, so beware - not fully tested! Also, the indexing does not yet properly handle duplicate field values - adding Child('1234','bob') and Child('2550','bob') will blow its mind. self._index should properly be a dict of list, which then needs some extra code in _delindex to remove the correct object; __getitem__ should return just the first value, and there should be a findAll method which returns the entire list; also I am thinking about separate per-attribute indexes such that you could do classroom.children[id=3] while defaulting to search-on-all-attributes.

Comment: Added __contains__ and get functions. Modified __getitem__ to return keyerror. Created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/895134

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass the [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class. For example:

```
import collections

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Child(\'%s\', \'%s\')' % (self.id, self.name)

class MyOrderedDict(collections.OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(MyOrderedDict, self).__init__()
        if len(args) > 0:
            for i in args[0]:
                super(MyOrderedDict, self).__setitem__(i.id, i)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return super(MyOrderedDict, self).__getitem__(self.keys()[key])
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return [super(MyOrderedDict, self).__getitem__(k) for k in self.keys()[key]]
        return super(MyOrderedDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def append(self, item):
        super(MyOrderedDict, self).__setitem__(item.id, item)

    def pop(self, key = None, default = object()):
        if key is None:
            return self.popitem()
        return super(MyOrderedDict, self).pop(self.keys()[key], default = default)


class Classroom(object):
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.children = MyOrderedDict(children)

classroom = Classroom([Child('389', 'pete')])
print repr(classroom.children[0])
classroom.children.append(Child('2344', 'joe'))
print repr(classroom.children.pop(0))
print repr(classroom.children['2344'])
print repr(classroom.children[0:1])
```

This code outputs:

```
Child('389', 'pete')
Child('389', 'pete')
Child('2344', 'joe')
[Child('2344', 'joe')]
```

Comment: OrderedDict is only available in python 2.7 I believe? Any way to do this in 2.6?

Comment: Got it working with the pypi version of OrderedDict, but it breaks on other list operations like classroom.children[0:1]

Comment: I'll edit the answer above to enable the __getitem__ method to support slices.

Comment: Is there a reason it can't be the other way around - subclassing list and using composition to store a dict? I'd rather not add another external module dependency if I don't have to.

Comment: Yes, you can subclass `list` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is some code you wanted to avoid, but for small scale objects performance should be tolerable. I think it is at least within your constraint: *I'd also like to avoid as much code as possible.*

```
class Classroom(object):
    """ Left out the teachers part for simplicity """

    def __init__(self, children):
        self.children = children        
        self._child_by_id = {}

    @property
    def child_by_id(self):
        """ Return a dictionary with Child ids as keys and Child objects
            as corresponding values. 
        """
        self._child_by_id.clear()
        for child in self.children:
            self._child_by_id[child.id] = child
        return self._child_by_id
```

This will be always up-to-date, since it is computed on the fly. 
A little more optimized version could look like this:

```
    ...

    @property
    def child_by_id(self):
        scbi, sc = self._child_by_id, self.children
        scbi.clear()
        for child in sc:
            scbi[child.id] = child
        return scbi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant:

```
class Classroom(object):
    def __init__(self, objects):
        for obj in objects:
            self.add(obj)

    def add(self, obj):
        name = obj.__class__.__name__ + "ById"
        if name not in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[name] = {}
        self.__dict__[name][obj.id] = obj

    def remove(self, obj):        
        name = obj.__class__.__name__ + "ById"
        del self.__dict__[name][obj.id]

    def listOf(self, name):
        return self.__dict__[name + "ById"].values()

classroom = Classroom([Child('389','pete'),
                       Teacher('829','bob')])

print classroom.ChildById['389']
classroom.ChildById['123'] = Child('123', 'gabe')
print classroom.listOf('Child')
classroom.remove(classroom.listOf('Teacher')[0])
print classroom.TeacherById
```

It lets you get inconsistent by allowing you to do `classroom.ChildById['123'] = Teacher('456', 'gabe')` but it might be good enough to do what you're looking for.